# WordPress (WooCommerce): Using SELECT to get order_total for 30 days (Getting total revenue amount)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, woocommerce

I have a code that suppose to connect to WordPress database and get `_order_total` from `shop_order` (WooCommerce Plugin) for custom date. Here is my function:

```
<?php
function get_total_income_a(){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        AND p.post_date BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-02'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total'
    " );
}
?>
```

And this is code that echo total orders value:

```
<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a() ) ?>
```

**These codes works fine for defined date in the code. But I have some questions**:

1. The `AND p.post_date BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-02'` should select only one day. Is there any alternative for this? I mean instead of defining a range, How can I only enter one date. For example what if I only want to get data only for `2023-09-01` date? Just for a shorthand.
2. As you can see my code, It will return data for only one date. I want to create a chart and need this value for 30 days. So in a very beginner and simple mode, I have to copy this code once for each day and change the date! That means I have to copy the above code 30 times! Is there any lighter and simpler way to doing this? I mean keeping one `SELECT` and using only codes like these to get data from custom date:

```
// Get data for 2023-09-01:
<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a('2023-09-01') ) ?>

// Get data for 2023-09-02:
<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a('2023-09-02') ) ?>

// Get data for 2023-09-03:
<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a('2023-09-03') ) ?>

// And so on until the end of the month
```

Comment: 1. `DATE(p.post_date) = '2023-09-01'`

Comment: But for 2., you'd rather want to keep using BETWEEN. Combine that with `GROUP BY DATE(p.post_date)`, and add `DATE(p.post_date)` to your column list. And perhaps ORDER BY the same value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question: Since 'post_date' is of type 'datetime' and you want to ignore the time part to select a whole day, you can either use a string comparison or cast to 'date':

```
AND p.post_date LIKE '2023-09-01%'
```

or

```
AND CAST(p.post_date AS DATE) = '2023-09-01'
```

As for your second question, you simply need to group results by post_date. Again, since this is a datetime column, you also need a cast it to date:

```
GROUP BY CAST(p.post_date AS DATE)
```

This will, of course, return an array, so you want to use 'get_results' instead of 'get_var'. To add the post_date to the resultset, also add the cast to your select:

```
SELECT CAST(p.post_date AS date), SUM(pm.meta_value)
```

So the full (untested) function could look as follows:

```
<?php
function get_total_income_a(){
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT CAST(p.post_date AS DATE), SUM(pm.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
        AND p.post_date BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-26'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_order_total' 
        GROUP BY CAST(p.post_date AS DATE)
    " );
}
?>
```

Edit: As @CBroe pointed out in the comments, 'DATE(p.post_date)' should work just as fine as 'CAST(p.post_date AS DATE)' in this case.

Comment: Thanks and how can i get variable data from this SQL? I mean a code like `<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a('2023-09-01') ) ?>` and `<?php echo strip_tags( get_total_income_a('2023-09-02') ) ?>` for getting data from one SQL statement? Or should i copy SQL for each dates?

Comment: You would add parameters to the function declaration like "function get_total_income_a($from_date, $to_date){.." and then use these variables instead of the fixed dates inside the statement like "AND p.post_date BETWEEN '{$from_date}' AND '{$to_date}'". If you don't trust the parameters, make sure to use wpdb->prepare.